# PHP sqlsrv Stored procedure with Table result AND variable output causes crash

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a huge legacy Stored Procedure which outputs a table and 2 variables.
The reason for this is that sometimes the SP has to be nested and to avoid nested SP errors the output is  returned in both formats.

PHP v8
SQL Server 2017

The input parameters of the SP are:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_QueryMileageDataFromPostcodes]
    (
        @Postcode1 VARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @Postcode2 VARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @Latitude1 FLOAT  = NULL,
        @Longitude1 FLOAT = NULL,
        @Latitude2 FLOAT = NULL,
        @Longitude2 FLOAT = NULL,
        @OutputDistanceMiles Float = NULL OUTPUT,
        @OutputDistanceKilometers Float = NULL OUTPUT
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

....

** processing within stored procedure **

....

SET @OutputDistanceMiles = 
    (
        SELECT
            MilesValue
        FROM 
            @PostcodeMileage
        WHERE 
            (Meters IS NOT NULL)
    )

SET @OutputDistanceKilometers = 
    (
        SELECT
            KilometersValue
        FROM 
            @PostcodeMileage
        WHERE 
            (Meters IS NOT NULL)
    )

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    @PostcodeMileage
WHERE 
    (Meters IS NOT NULL)
```

My PHP code is:

```
$SQLStmt = "EXEC Postcodetools.dbo.usp_QueryMileageDataFromPostcodes @Postcode1='BH21 2SR',@Postcode2='HP234AB';";
$RS_Result01 = sqlsrv_query($conn01,$SQLStmt);
$ROW_test01 = sqlsrv_fetch($RS_Result01,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which returns an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sqlsrv_fetch(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type resource, bool given in...
```

I tested further with:

```
$SQLStmt = "EXEC Postcodetools.dbo.usp_QueryMileageDataFromPostcodes @Postcode1='BH21 5PD',@Postcode2='HP23 4PD';";
$RS_Result01 = sqlsrv_query($conn01,$SQLStmt);
var_dump($RS_Result01);
```

and that gave me a result of `bool(false)`

Is this there any fundamental issue with the sqlsrv driver and a Stored Procedure Operating in this way?

Is there a way of allowing me to get the table output?

Comment: Missing a closing quote on your first parameter.

Comment: Spotted and edited. Thank you. However that was a typo during the writing of the question and does not affect the issue.

Comment: The problem isn't with `sqlsrv_fetch()`. Read the error message again: `sqlsrv_fetch(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type resource, bool given in[stead]`. That means that `$RS_Result01` is a bool value, which is explained by reading the [sqlsrv_query() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php): _Returns a statement resource on success and false if an error occurred._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that outputting a table AND variables is a viable solution in a stored procedure with the drivers for PHP.

The issue turned out to be a `PRINT` statement buried in the stored procedure. The stored procedure is about 1000 lines of code and the `PRINT` was probably left in by accident by the developer during testing (ten years ago?).
It was not outputting anything and therefor returned a blank line when the procedure was run in SSMS; not easy to spot unless you are looking for it.

To confuse matters more the legacy Classic ASP page was using a driver that happily return the record set without issue. It ran for years like that. When we ported the calling web page to PHP the `PRINT` statement caused the errors shown above, which is why I was questioning the driver.

Many thanks for all those that have contributed to this question.